# Android Wifi broadcast receiver not working as expected

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi

I have to get the WiFi ssid whenever phone connects to new WiFi network. I registered the following

```
receiver `registerReceiver(this.mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION));`
```

This part of code works perfectly. But in `onReceive` method,

```
NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO));
```

always returns null.  I tried `EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO` as well, but it also returns Null.

I can't use

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));,
```

as the service will stop/start after n minutes and using this will generate the event on every restart of service.

Any ideas that how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can create broadcast within the activity***

> **Step 1 :**

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        registerReceiver();
        super.onResume();
    }

 private void registerReceiver() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
```

> **Step 2**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (info != null) {
                if (info.isConnected()) {
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
                    if (ssid != null) {
                        if (isConnectClicked) {
                          //YOUR CONNECTED WITH WIFI

                                               } 
                                      }
                                         }

                               }
            } else {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                    if (intent.hasExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR)) {

                  //Connection failed    


                    }
                }
             }
          }

    };
```

> **Step 3**

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I also have a similar one. But the problem is that my code stops/starts the services after every 2 minutes. In this case the event is generated every two minutes, is there any way out for this?

Comment: Thanks I solved the issue, your solution helped me to think more clearly!

Comment: Solution is good, but what if connection fail due to wrong passkey while adding or updating network? EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR is not working in that case. if you have any related solution?