# Can not connect another android device with wifi with android lollipop

Tags: android, wifi

> Hello, I am trying to connect two android device through wifi. here one 
>   device was providing hotspot and another device will connect available 
>   wifi. In here am using following code to connect with wifi

```
mainWifi = (WifiManager)device_list.this. getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
mainWifi.startScan();
 WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();




        wifiConfig.SSID = sr.SSID;
        wifiConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;


        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfig.priority = 40;


        netId = mainWifi.addNetwork(wifiConfig);

            mainWifi.disconnect();
            mainWifi.enableNetwork(netId, true);
            mainWifi.reconnect();
```

> The above code is working perfect in lower version and i had problem 
>   with android lollipop. with android lollipop i can not connect with 
>   wifi, it fallback with previous one, so i am waiting for perfect 
>   solution for this issue. thank you.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889089/android-connect-to-open-wifi-programmatically-by-name-which-is-best-solution/30889687#30889687 &http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284285/android-wifi-broadcast-receiver-not-working-as-expected/31284820#31284820

Comment: @AnoopM thanks for your response, is this will work with lollipop, because i had no issue with lower version i have issue on android lollipop only

Comment: It might be work give a try..

Comment: @AnoopM Thanks it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I fixed this problem by updating the API. 
Every Operating system kernel Designer provides API, for Application programmers, that changes from time to time.

> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html
>   https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

May these will help for you also.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.